# Rails 3 inline errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new in rails 3. I'm using bootstrap and i want to display the validation errors next to the invalid field.

here is the code

```
<div class="control-group <%= @pet.errors.has_key?(:nick) ? "error": "" %>">
        <%= f.label :nick, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
            <%= f.text_field :nick, :class => 'text_field' %>
            <% unless !@pet.errors.has_key?(:nick)%>
            <span class="help-inline"><%= @pet.errors[:nick]%></span>
            <%end%>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my problem is that `<%= @pet.errors[:nick]%>`returns

```
["no puede estar en blanco"]
```

and must be just

```
no puede estar en blanco
```

here you have an image

http://img848.imageshack.us/img848/8263/inlineerror.jpg

is there any way i can get the error message without the square brackets and the quotation marks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Field errors are a collection, not a single error--there can be more than one error per field.

Comment: `if condition` is probably easier to understand than `unless !condition`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
<span class="help-inline"><%= @pet.errors[:nick].join(", ")%></span>
```

Comment: Or `f.object.errors[:nick].join(", ")` if you are using `form_for` and want to be more generic.

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets around the string indicate that it's an array. You could also get rid of the brackets and quotation marks by writing

```
<%= @pet.errors[:nick][0]%>
```